# How to disable a service when "access is denied"?

Tags: windows-7, security, services

Some services sometime cannot be disabled in Windows 7, even though I think they could be (such as annoying antiviruses). When I try to do so from services.msc, there's an "Access is denied" error.

Is there any way to go around this error and disable it anyway? I assume I could reboot in safe mode but I'm looking for a simpler solution. Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: Do you have admin credentials on your Windows machine ?

Comment: Yes I have admin credentials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: You cannot.

The reason is that the "Access is denied" behaviour is enforced by a device driver that is most probably a file system driver that checks for specific actions on specific files and denies those operations.

The only way you can do so is:

1. disable the access protection behaviour through the AVs UI.
2. Boot into safe mode (Most of the times not useful because today almost all antiviruses add themselves to the minimal boot drivers list used by safe mode)
3. Use a Windows Minimal Environment like BartPE to boot up and modify the registry to not start the service / load the driver at boot.

Answer (score 9):

I used **autoruns.exe** from sysinternals (microsoft)

Went to 'Services' tab and un-ticked MsMpSvc. Rebooted.

I could enabled it again using the same steps.

Comment: +1 Autoruns worked for me. Doing a POC of Cylance Protect, and had one DEV server I could not remove the agent from. The MSI uninstall command would fail to stop the service, and therefore not remove the agent. Even tried in Safe Mode. Autoruns took care of it for me. Thank you!